# Hair deforming when I move eyebrows

Tags: rigging, bones, hair, rigify

In my Rigify rig when I move the eyebrows, the hair deforms. It pulls the hair in different directions. I parented the hair to the rig with empty groups. Then assigned it to the head bone (spine 6) and parented the eyebrows to the rig with empty groups. Then assigned them to brow left and brow right bones. The rest of the body I parented to the rig with automatic weights.

Comment: Sounds good what you did. When the hair moves with the eyebrow there must be some weights from other bones. In the *Edit* mode you can select a vertice and check the assigned weights in the N-panel. There is also an overlay that displays the weights in *Edit* mode similar to the *Weight Paint* mode. (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/vertex_weights.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!